# C pass a nested structure within a structure to a function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, nested

I have a address to a nested struct problem that I haven't been able to solve for a while right now.

So I have a ModuleStruct that holds a sensorStruct.
No problem to pass the address to the ModuleStruct in main. But when I do want to pass the address to the inner struct "SensorStruct" so readVoltage function can store the values, It fails. 
Been googling and checking StackOverflow without finding anything that works. I hope I just done something stupid so it's easy to get it going.

Will be super happy if anyone could point me in the right direction (*puufh ;) )

```
typedef struct
{
    int32_t Voltage;
    int32_t Current;
}SensorStruct;

typedef struct
{
    SensorStruct SensorData;
}ModuleStruct;


int main(void)
{
    ModuleStruct Module_Data;

    Sensor_Collect(&Module_Data);
}

void Sensor_Collect(ModuleStruct *Module_Data)
{
    /// Here is the problem, I do not know how to pass the address of the SensorStruct
    ReadVoltage(Module_Data->SensorData);   
}

void ReadVoltage(SensorStruct *Sensor_Data)
{
    Sensor_Data->Voltage = 5;
    Sensor_Data->Current = 3;
}
```

Comment: `ReadVoltage(&(Module_Data->SensorData));`

Comment: Yeep tried that with no luck, thanks

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and see [ask]. "tried that with no luck" is not **specific** problem description.

Comment: @molbdnilo: No, they are not. The arrow operator has higher preceedence than the address-of operator.

Comment: It will fail ONLY if you don't have forward function declarations. Below I'll add an answer with code that 100% works.

Comment: @Olaf Brain malfunction. Probably sunspots.

Answer (score 4):

Code that works. Take note that `Sensor_Collect` function is defined **after** `ReadVoltage` function, so it knows it's type when it calls it. Always compile your code with all warnings turned on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    int32_t Voltage;
    int32_t Current;
} SensorStruct;

typedef struct {
    SensorStruct SensorData;
} ModuleStruct;

void ReadVoltage(SensorStruct *Sensor_Data) {
    Sensor_Data->Voltage = 5;
    Sensor_Data->Current = 3;
}

void Sensor_Collect(ModuleStruct *Module_Data) {
    ReadVoltage(&(Module_Data->SensorData));   
}

int main(void) {
    ModuleStruct Module_Data;

    Sensor_Collect(&Module_Data);
    printf("voltage: %d\n", Module_Data.SensorData.Voltage);
    printf("current: %d\n", Module_Data.SensorData.Current);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will make a new project and check. But for the one I am working on, It's not working. If I create a new SensorStruct in the sensor_Collect function, and pass that into ReadVoltage, It get the right values. But not with the &(Module_Data->SensorData). If I read the memory address for the main structure its fine , but when I check the ->SensorData I get 0x25 . so I do Not really know whats going on. Tanks for answer :)