# Pass nested struct to a function

Tags: c++, struct, parameters, reference

Hello I have the following code:

```
struct temperatures_t {
  char lowTempSetting = 18;
  char highTempSetting = 26;
  char currentTemp = 23;
};

struct runningState_t {
  struct temperatures_t temperatures;
};

struct runningState_t runningState;

void test(runningState_t *runningStateVar) {
  runningStateVar->temperatures->lowTempSetting++;
  runningStateVar->temperatures->currentTemp = 10;
  printf(runningStateVar.temperatures.lowTempSetting);
}

void main() {
  test(&runningState);
}
```

But getting the following error on the `runningState->temperatures->` lines:

```
{
"message": "operator -> or ->* applied to \"temperatures_t\" instead of to a pointer type"
}
```

I have also tried variations:

```
  &(runningState)->temperatures->lowTempSetting++;
```

And other variations based off what I saw in this answer: [C pass a nested structure within a structure to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588021/c-pass-a-nested-structure-within-a-structure-to-a-function)

But without much luck

Comment: The code you show isn't valid C code. C doesn't allow structure inline initialization like you have. Are you perhaps building C++ code? What is the full file-name of the source file? How do you build it? And about invalid code, that `printf` call is wrong as well.

Comment: On another note, if you want small integers use the type `int8_t` instead. Or just use plain `int`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry! Clicked the wrong tag. Have updated appropriately!

Comment: Then I recommend you stop using pointers when passing structures, and instead start using *references*. And you also don't need the `struct` keyword when declaring variables, as the structure tag-name is a type-name similar to e.g. `int`. And don't use `printf` to print but `std::cout`.

Comment: Also since you're programming in C++ you should be careful also with `int8_t` since it's usually based on `char`, which means when you print it with `std::cout` and `<<` it will be printed as a characters not a small integer. Use plain `int` even for small integers. And do input-validation to make sure that users don't enter invalid or out-of-range values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is being compiled to a M5Stack microcontroller. Unfortunately it seems it doesn't have `int8_t` or `std::cout`, but will keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `test`, the local argument variable `runningState` (not to be confused with the global variable of the same name) is a pointer to a structure object, so the arrow operator `->` is the correct to use to access its members.

But `runningState->temperatures` is *not* a pointer, it's an actual structure object. Therefore you must use the dot `.` to access its members:

```
runningState->temperatures.lowTempSetting++;
//                        ^
//      Note using dot here
```

Comment: Yep, this code was trimmed down and taken from 3 separate files. When I try `runningState->temperatures.lowTempSetting++` I get `request for member 'temperatures' in 'runningState', which is of pointer type 'runningState_t*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)`.FYI, I have this struct defined in a header that both cpp files include at the top. The `struct runningState_t runningState;` is at the top of the main.cpp file.

Comment: Actually your answer is correct. My VSCode wasn't updating the "problems" it was "detecting", but it compiled just fine when trying it. What tipped me off is that it was having compiler errors on a comment. Uhhg. Thank you!